# Svelte - `&:nth-child()` doesn't work for elements which created by {#each}

Tags: css-selectors, svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    let buttons: Array<{ buttonName: string; className: string; id: number }>;

    buttons = [
        { buttonName: 'NEW GAME', className: 'home-start', id: 1 },
        { buttonName: 'SETTINGS', className: 'home-setup', id: 2 },
        { buttonName: 'HOW TO PLAY', className: 'home-help', id: 3 },
    ];
</script>

<style land="sass">
    .buttons
        :nth-child(n+2)
            background-color: red
</style>

<template>
    <div class="buttons">
        {#each buttons as button (button.id)}
            <Button
                className="{button.className} button"
                on:click={()=>{console.log(button.className)}}>
                {button.buttonName}
            </Button>
        {/each}
    </div>
</template>
```

The `nth-child()` selector doesn't work, but it works on those elements which were hard coded in.
How can I solve this?

This is my first question here, and my english isn't good enough though, but I still hope it makes sense. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element you render in the `#each` is not part of this component, so the styles will be discarded.  This is because svelte has no way to know to which element to apply this style. For all it's worth your `Button` component looks like this

```html
<div></div>
<button></button>
```

You can get around this by adding `:global` to your selector:

```css
.buttons > :global(:nth-child(n+2) {
   background-color: red
}
```

(This uses regular css, but you should be able to translate it to sass)

[Docs about :global](https://svelte.dev/docs#style)

Comment: Also `nth-child` should be related to siblings not parent. In this answer `>` selects parent’s children ie. siblings. Here is REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/74590730c3ae4249953f6847da4af4c6?version=3.24.1

Comment: WOW! IT WORKS! I'm so exciting with your solution. YOU ROCK! I've been working for a solution like 2 hours and I've also tried `:global()`, but never thought to put `nth-child()` into the `global()`. Thanks a lot man, you just saved my day!

Comment: Thanks for this one, mate! I have spent a few minutes on debugging and had no idea why it doesn't work.